# socket.io node.js and laravel problem server

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel

I have server node.js I have worked with freamwork laravel There are two ports localhost:8000 for laravel and localhost:5000 for node server .
When it works on localhost there are no problems .
But when it works online The port stops working and gives a message :

> "Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?user_id=12&first_name=abbod&mylist=1%2C2%2C10%2C11%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16&status=online&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdL48w6”[Learn
>   More] socket.io.js:7:4086 "

---

**this is my files : server.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const http    = require('http');
const socket  = require('socket.io');


const SocketServer = require('./socket');

class Server {

    constructor()
    {
        this.port = 5000 ;
        this.host = 'localhost';

        this.app = express();
        this.http = http.Server(this.app); // Node Js Server
        this.socket = socket(this.http); // here run a Socket io module
    }
    runServer()
    {
        new SocketServer(this.socket).socketConnection(); // this is socket Class

        /* Listening a node js server */
        this.http.listen(this.port,this.host,()=> {
           console.log( `the server is running at http://${this.host}:${this.port}`);
        });
        /* Listening a node js server */
    }
}

const app = new Server();
app.runServer(); // run the Serve Class
```

**File silence has no problem Not displayed**

### **and this is page client :** Here is the exact problem But I do not know how to solve it

```
 //// resolve refresh status
        var my_status = $('input[name="status"]:checked').val();    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000',{       
query: 'user_id='+user_id+'&first_name='+first_name+'&mylist='+mylist.join(',')+'&status='+my_status    });
        // array for emit
        var array_emit = ['is_online','iam_online','iam_offline','new_status'];
        // function for all emit status connection
        $.each(array_emit,function (key,value) {
            socket.on(value,function (data) {
                statusUser(data.user_id,data.status);
                if (data.status === 'online')
                {
                    $('.status_string_'+data.user_id).text('active now');
                }else if(data.status === 'offline')
                {
                    $('.status_string_'+data.user_id).text('Inactive');
                }else if(data.status === 'bys')
                {
                    $('.status_string_'+data.user_id).text('Busy');
                }else
                {
                    $('.status_string_'+data.user_id).text('DND');
                }
            });
        }); // send my friends i online     socket.on('connect',function (data) {       $('.user-chat').each(function () {          var uid = $(this).data('id');           socket.emit('check_online',{
                    user_id:'user_'+uid             });
            });
        });
```

---

Comment: If I am not wrong, socket emits data based on https. Please deploy your Laravel app with either TLS or SSL certificate, and try again.

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović web socket can use also `ws://` or `wss://` in case of web secure socket